# how to display a parsed string as seperate items in html

Tags: java, database, jsp, struts2, struts

I'm trying to print out an entire database table from a java class onto a JSP page. I have the means to print the string I want, but I don't know where to go from there. I'm using struts2 if that makes a difference.

> ```
> <s:property value="stringIWantToMakeIntoAnHTMLTable" />
> ```

Comment: What is the contents of `stringIWantToMakeIntoAnHTMLTable`?

Comment: well ideally it would be the entire ResultSet from a query, but I'm ok just parsing a string for each record.

Comment: We need more information. is it just a space delimited list of words?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose your table is for students list, create a bean class for student that have the fields in database. Then in Java page

```
    List li=new ArrayList()
    while(resultset.next())
    {
    //Read value from database
    Student s=new Student(fields in beanclass);
    li.add(s)
}
```

enter code here
}

Keep that list in request/session attribute.
In Jsp, use

`<s:iterator>` tag of Struts2 to read values.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing @Yaswanth's answer, once you have the list of Students, you can use the `s:iterator` tag in the JSP. It'll look something like :

```
<table>
<s:iterator value="lstStudents">
    <tr>
    <td class="text-left"> 
        <s:a href="/view/%{idstudent}">
            <s:property value="name"/>
        </s:a>
    </td>
    <td style="color: <s:property value="%{profitpercent>0?'#3ead3e':'red'}"/>">
          <s:property value="email"/>
    </td>
</s:iterator>
</table>
```